# Querying xml in SQL Server with Soap envelope

Tags: sql-server, xml, soap

I have found many examples for handling soap namespaces in an xml field, but none have helped me with my case:

I am trying to query a single element in the xml example below. (I truncated the example so you won't see the closing elements, but it is properly formed.)

Here is the xml:

```
<soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"     xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/TransactionDataSchema" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<PRPA_IN201305UV02 xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" ITSVersion="XML_1.0">
<id extension="123abc-12a3-123a-a1bc-0a0a0a0a0a0a" root="1.23.456.7.890123.4.5678.901.2.3.4" />
<creationTime value="20150602175238" />
<interactionId extension="PRPA_IN201305UV02" root="1.23.456.7.890123.4.5" />
<processingCode code="P" />
<processingModeCode code="T" />
<acceptAckCode code="AL" />
<receiver typeCode="RCV">
  <device classCode="DEV" determinerCode="INSTANCE">
    <id root="1.23.456.7.890123.4.5678.001.1" />
    <telecom value="https://stage.mysite.org:1111/myevent" />
etc …
```

Here is the query I started with (Request_Body is the xml field in the table), though I believe the issue has something to do with the xml namespace - I'm just not sure what:

```
SELECT
Request_Body.value
('(/soapenv:Body/PRPA_IN201305UV02[@xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3"]/receiver/device/id/telecom)[1]', 'varchar(100)' )
FROM [SW_Reporting].[dbo].[Client_Request]
```

Here is the error i got with my original query above:

```
Msg 2229, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
XQuery [SW_Reporting.dbo.Client_Request.Request_Body.value()]: The name "soapenv" does not denote a namespace.
```

I've tried using `With xmlnamespaces` and I got the select to return the whole xml using just '/' by itself. And I got everything after the second element (`<PRPA_IN201305UV02`), too, using a couple of namespace prefixes:

```
WITH xmlnamespaces (
'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope' as soapenv
,'urn:hl7-org:v3' as ns1)
```

But I can't get anything deeper than that. I am able to get a NULL value in some cases, so at least my syntax is accepted, but I know there is data to retrieve.

Here's my latest query, which isn't working either (after dumping the xml into a table variable):

```
declare @table table (data xml);
insert into @table values (@xml);

WITH xmlnamespaces (
'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope' as soapenv   
,'urn:hl7-org:v3' as ns1)
SELECT Data.query
('/soapenv:Body/ns1:PRPA_IN201305UV02/creationTime') as test
FROM @Table ;
```

I have queried xml before, but not with all the soap stuff. I appreciate any help/suggestions. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you missed is the fact that descendant elements inherit ancestor default namespace *implicitly*, unless otherwise specified. That means, in this particular XML, all elements without prefix are in default namespace which uri is `"urn:hl7-org:v3"`, and you need to use corresponding prefix to reference those elements in your XPath/XQuery :

```
WITH xmlnamespaces (
'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope' as soapenv   
,'urn:hl7-org:v3' as ns1)
SELECT Data.query
('/soapenv:Body/ns1:PRPA_IN201305UV02/ns1:creationTime') as test
FROM @Table ;                       --^^^
                                    --Notice `ns1` prefix added here
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks very much! I needed to specify the prefix all the way through. Although I got the solution, I'm still a little confused by how you wrote your answer. It seems like you said that any element without a specified prefix gets the default prefix, which in this case is `urn:hl7-org:v3`. But, that is also the value of ns1, so it seems like I'm replacing the default value with the same string. What am I missing?